# dask.delayed memory management when a single task can consume a lot of memory outside of python

Tags: dask, pardiso

I have some calculations calling the pardiso() solver from python.  The solver allocates its own memory in a way that is opaque to python, but the pointers used to access that memory are stored in python.  If I were to try and run these calculations using dask.delayed is there any way to tell dask the expected memory consumption of the calculation so that it can schedule them appropriately?

Comment: Could I ask you to provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two solutions to a situation where there is some constraint that dask should respect: `resources` argument and `Semaphore`.

For the resources the workflow is to allocate some amount of resources to each worker (either via cli when launching the workers or using `resources` kwarg in `LocalCluster` or another type of cluster). Then, the code would specify how much of this resource is used by each task at the time of `.compute` or `.map/.submit`.

The workflow with `Semaphore` is to specify the number of leases possible (note that unlike resources this is an integer, so in some sense less flexible) when creating the Semaphore (see [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#coordination-primitives)). Then whenever the costly resource is accessed it should be wrapped in `with sem` context manager.